# pythonにおけるhashlibについて

Tags: python, python3

windows10にてpython3.4でhashlibを使うため、pip install hashlibを行ったところ、以下のエラーが発生してしまいました。解決法、または代替可能なライブラリなどを教えていただけますと幸いです。

> raise ValueError, "unsupported hash type"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pipを使ってinstallしなくてもpython3.4であれば、ふつうに`import hashlib`で使えるようになると思います。